# R: change one value every row in big dataframe

Tags: r

I just started working with R for my master thesis and up to now all my calculations worked out as I read a lot of questions and answers here (and it's a lot of trial and error, but thats ok).
Now i need to process a more sophisticated code and i can't find a way to do this.

Thats the situation: I have multiple sub-data-sets with a lot of entries, but they are all structured in the same way. In one of them (50000 entries) I want to change only one value every row. The new value should be the amount of the existing entry plus a few values from another sub-data-set (140000 entries) where the 'ID'-variable is the same.

As this is the third day I'm trying to solve this, I already found and tested `for` and `apply` but both are running for hours (canceled after three hours). 
Here is an example of one of my attempts (with `for`):

```
for (i in 1:50000) {
  Entry_ID <- Sub02[i,4] 
  SUM_Entries <- sum(Sub03$Source==Entry_ID) 
  Entries_w_ID <- subset(Sub03, grepl(Entry_ID, Sub03$Source)) # The Entry_ID/Source is a character

  Value1 <- as.numeric(Entries_w_ID$VAL1) 
  SUM_Value1 <- sum(Value1)
  Value2 <- as.numeric(Entries_w_ID$VAL2)
  SUM_Value2 <- sum(Value2)

  OLD_Val1 <- Sub02[i,13]
  OLD_Val <- as.numeric(OLD_Val1)
  NEW_Val <- SUM_Entries + SUM_Value1 + SUM_Value2 + OLD_Val

  Sub02[i,13] <- NEW_Val

}
```

I know this might be a silly code, but thats the way I tried it as a beginner. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out with this so I can get along with my thesis. 
Thank you!

Here's an example of my data-structure:

```
        Text VAL0 Source ID VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4 VAL5 VAL6 VAL7 VAL8 VAL9
XXX 12 456335667806925_1075080942599058 10153901516433434_10153902087098434 4 1 0 0 4 9 4 6 8
ABC 8 456335667806925_1057045047735981 10153677787178434_10153677793613434 6 7 1 1 5 3 6 8 11
DEF 8 456747267806925_2357045047735981 45653677787178434_94153677793613434 5 8 2 1 5 4 1 1 9
```

The output I expect is an updated value 'VAL9' in every row.

Comment: Could you give as first row's of your data and make reproducible example, please.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and your expected output

Comment: Sorry about that. I just updated my post.

Comment: @trotta: I noticed that you are using `grepl` to match `ID` in `Sub02` to `Source` in `Sub03`. Is that necessary for partial matches or do you just have exact matches (i.e., `Sources` in `Sub03` that are the same characters as `IDs` in `Sub02`)?

Comment: No, thats not absolutely necessary, I only have exact matches. But this solution worked for me, so I kept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood so far, you need 2 things:

1. sum up some values in one dataset
2. add them to another dataset, using an ID variable

Besides what @yoland already contributed, I would suggest to break it down in two separate tasks. Consider these two datasets:

```
a = data.frame(x = 1:2, id = letters[1:2], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a
#   x id
# 1 1  a
# 2 2  b

b = data.frame(values = as.character(1:4), otherid = letters[1:2], 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sapply(b, class)
#      values     otherid 
# "character" "character"
```

Values is `character` now, we need to convert it to `numeric`:

```
b$values = as.numeric(b$values)
sapply(b, class)
#    values     otherid 
# "numeric" "character"
```

Then sum up the values in `b` (grouped by `otherid`):

```
library(dplyr)

b = group_by(b, otherid)
b = summarise(b, sum_values = sum(values))
b
#   otherid sum_values
#     <chr>      <dbl>
# 1       a          4
# 2       b          6
```

Then join it with `a` - note that identifiers are specified in `c()`:

```
ab = left_join(a, b, by = c("id" = "otherid"))
ab
#   x id sum_values
# 1 1  a          4
# 2 2  b          6
```

We can then add the result of the sum from `b` to the variable `x` in `a`:

```
ab$total = ab$x + ab$sum_values
ab
#   x id sum_values total
# 1 1  a          4     5
# 2 2  b          6     8
```

(Updated.)

Comment: Thats very close, thank you. But there are some problems left: The index value is called 'ID' in dataset a and 'Source' in dataset b. And all values (even those I try to sum up) seem to be characters.

Comment: See updated answer for converting `character` to `numeric`, and joining by different ids. If you need also the counts of ids in `b`, add for instance `idcount = n()` within the `summarise` call. Then it will get joined with `a` as well.

Comment: And check out help for [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), as it is especially useful in these cases and mastering it will pay off *a lot* in the future.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much! To count the rows with the matching IDs: `b = summarise(b, sum_values = sum(values), sum_rows = n(otherid))` ?

Comment: Almost :) But `n()` does not take any arguments, it just counts all the rows. And, because the rows have been already groupped by "otherid" with `group_by`, it will count the rows *within* each group. See help for `n()` (by calling `?n` in the console).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to create a new variable that uses information from two different data sets indexed by the same `ID`. The easiest way to do this is probably to join the data sets together (if you need to safe memory, just join the columns you need). I found `dplyr`'s join functions very handy for these cases (explained neatly [here](http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html)) Once you joined the data sets into one, it should be easy to create the new columns you need.  e.g.: `df$new <- df$old1 + df$old2`